# codenameone app with sliding menu

Tags: codenameone

new to codename one, and I'm looking to build a fairly robust app. I've read a lot of codename one documentation and have looked through many of the demos on git. My question is, what is the best way to architect the application?

Here are my basic requirements:

- Splash screen
- Lock screen (enabled/disabled by user)
- Sliding (hamburger) menu
- Contents of sliding menu will change based on current 'form'
- Application settings

Based on this short list of requirements, would it better to make each different screen a form, and the sliding menu for each a different 'instance', or make a main form that contains the sliding menu (and just change contents of menu based on current screen) and make each different screen a component instead of a form?

Also, I was considering coding it by hand, and not using the gui builder.

Thank you.

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with separate forms mostly because of the hassle of updating the side menu for every selection you make. This would also make the general design more flexible.